# Multiple audio files running on raspberry

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a small homeproject and I need to be able to start a song and then keep track of it (like save it to a variable or something) so I can adjust the volume of certain sound files without changing others. I've looked into pygame and I get the sound file to play with

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("myFile.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

but with this I cant start another song and adjust the volume of the first song without changing the second one. Is it possible to save the first song in a variable so i can use the set_volume() function on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup `channels` for each song , add song to each channel and then manipulate channel instead of music object.

Here is a working code. It changes volume differently for each song thats added to each channel. The program assumes all songs in `audio` folder within your current working directory.

The program is oversimplified to illustrate concept. You can of course create list of songs and channels then add and manipulate them based on index.

**Program**

```
import pygame

def checkifComplete(channel):
    while channel.get_busy():  #Check if Channel is busy
        pygame.time.wait(800)  #  wait in ms
    channel.stop()             #Stop channel

if __name__ == "__main__":

    music_file1 = "sounds/audio1.wav"
    music_file2 = "sounds/audio2.wav"


    #set up the mixer
    freq = 44100     # audio CD quality
    bitsize = -16    # unsigned 16 bit
    channels = 2     # 1 is mono, 2 is stereo
    buffer = 2048    # number of samples (experiment to get right sound)
    pygame.mixer.init(freq, bitsize, channels, buffer)

    pygame.mixer.init() #Initialize Mixer

    #Create sound object for each Audio
    myAudio1 = pygame.mixer.Sound(music_file1)
    myAudio2 = pygame.mixer.Sound(music_file2)

    #Create a Channel for each Audio
    myChannel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
    myChannel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)

    #Add Audio to  first channel
    myAudio1.set_volume(0.8) # Reduce volume of first audio to 80%
    print "Playing audio : ", music_file1 
    myChannel1.play(myAudio1)
    checkifComplete(myChannel1) #Check if Audio1 complete

    #Add Audio to second channel
    myAudio2.set_volume(0.2)    # Reduce volume of first audio to 20%
    print "Playing audio : ", music_file2
    myChannel2.play(myAudio2)
    checkifComplete(myChannel2)
```

**Program Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit  (Intel)] on win32  
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.  
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================  
>>>   
Playing audio :  sounds/audio1.wav  
Playing audio :  sounds/audio2.wav  
>>>
```